# Unity - UI - Raw Image with Texture becomes Smaller after Build

Tags: unity, c#, gui

I am a beginner in the game development world, I have just one quick problem with the UI, as you can see during the Unity Player, the UI (Raw Image w/ Texture) is normal in size but when I build my game to APK or EXE and run it, the UI is small. Why is this happening and how to fix it?
[image]

Comment: Curious, why are you using RawImage components here instead of UI Image components with sprites? The latter will tend to have better performance due to batching.

Comment: DMGregory is right. Also, use the anchor to adjust with every UI size.

Answer (score 2):

From the information you provide it is most likely to assume that the elements that are getting wildly resized are all UI-Elements.

When placing UI-Elements, by default, Unity puts them into pixel-fixed positions rather than relative-positions. To fix that set the `Ui Scale Mode` on the `Canvas` holding all your UI-Elements to `Scale With Screen Size`, as detailed in [this answer on Unity Answers](http://answers.unity.com/answers/953828/view.html).

[image]
<sup>Screenshot from the linked Unity Answer in case it will ever go down.</sup>